# Best way to serve html using Jersey + Spring

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, jersey

I have a Web Application which uses Java, Jersey, Spring and Angular. All APIs are exposed via Jersey through this url "http://localhost:8080/webapp/api/".

But, as I am using Angular I need to serve an index.html file through "http://localhost:8080/webapp/index.html" and an admin index.html through "http://localhost:8080/webapp/admin/index.html". I want to know which is the best way to achieve this.

Jersey already uses a servlet, so I think of using this servlet to serve the index.html, but I don't like this idea, because I will mix api and html in the same servlet.

So, the second option is create another servlet just to serve this index.html.

I am open to suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: Just let the servlet container's default servlet serve it up, which it looks like you're already doing. There's no need to try and implement this. As long as your Jersey servlet is not mapped to `/*`, you shouldn't need any extra configuration for the default servlet to kick in

Comment: Yes, I agree. But, I forgot to mention that I have two routes: /webapp/index.html and /webapp/admin/index.html. Default servlet can handle this two routes ?

Comment: If you add an `admin` folder at the webapp root it should serve the index.html just be going to `/admin`